# PDO combine table headers with data

Tags: php, pdo, foreach, html-table

I am getting the name of the database table heads and data like this:

```
/* Get column names */
public function get_head($table) 
{
    $this->table = $table;
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("DESCRIBE ".$this->table);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
}

/* List all users */
public function get_users($table) 
{
    $this->table = $table;
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM ".$this->table);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

and they are output like this:

```
<table border=1>

<?php 

// Get headers
$columns = $user->get_head('login');

foreach ($columns as $col) 
{
    echo '<th>'.$col.'</th>';
}

// Get users
$users = $user->get_users('login');

foreach ($users as $user) 
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['user_id'].'. </td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['user_name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['email'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['password'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['role'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['last_login_date'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['date_created'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$user['status'].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>
```

How can I write the second foreach to generate the data automatically based on the names output by the first foreach of the table headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code where you want to show the data for each row, you can `foreach()` over the `$columns` and use the column name as the index to your user data...

```
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ( $columns as $column ) {
            echo '<td>'.$user[$column].'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: *facepal*, yeah I was totally on another planet with this. Thanks <3 :D